# Magento: How to limit a collection (sales/order) by a certain category?

Tags: magento, events, ecommerce-sales

I'm trying to limit order for admin users by category, I can find the collection of product `id` by category and collect sales/order but how can I use this with an event observer?

```
$category_id = 44;
$category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
  ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Next I collect just the product `id`s so I can use them:

```
$product_ids = array();
foreach ($products as $product)
  $product_ids[] = $product->getId();

$items = Mage::getModel("sales/order_item")->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter("product_id", array("in" => $product_ids));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SetPageSize and SetCurPage for that

> $col = Mage::getModel('YOUR MODEL')
>               ->getCollection()
>               ->setPageSize(17)
>               ->setCurPage(1);

HTH

Comment: @RatneshKumar: For me, it also works with the sales/order_item Model: $salesItems = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
  ->setPageSize(17);

Comment: yes it is that was my bad, actually when i iterate the collection it iterates through all the items in it. can you tell me why?

Comment: The error must be on your side, I iterate through it and I only get the 17 items...can you show me some code?